# How to verify existing Community users mobile number?

Tags: apex, community, mobile, customer-portal

I have implemented passwordless login using users mobile number for community and its working as expected. But It allows only verified mobile numbers. We have several existing community users in our org and their mobile numbers are not verified. Is there any way to verify the community users mobile number?